# Can a <Module> return a value in c#?

Tags: c#

so i'm trying to decrypt a string using aes256 and dnlib, when trying to decrypt, the program will  run, but will not call the <Module> , i think that is because of the internal class of the <Module>

looking at the program through a decompiler :

```
using System;
using System.IO;

// Token: 0x02000001 RID: 1
internal class <Module>
{
    // Token: 0x06000001 RID: 1 RVA: 0x00002624 File Offset: 0x00000824
    public static string Decrypt_(string A_0)
    {
        string result;
        try
        {
            result = Aes256._GetString(A_0);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

would it be possible to get a return value through a <Module>? just like in the code above

I'm using this but modified to aes256 : https://github.com/srn-g/EncryptStrings

Comment: Which modifications did you make? AES takes a key in addition to the input, how did you handle that?

Comment: the key and everything is generated randomly inside _GetString, the only problem is that i cannot call _GetString because it's internal and i have no idea how to make it public

Comment: Is `<Module>` a valid class name nowadays?

Comment: the <Module> class is used by .NET runtime to support module initializers, i'm using the github code above with some modifications, it will create a <Module>

Comment: That code was written in C++/CLI, a language that supports free functions (methods that are not part of a class).  Not something the CLR supports, so the function becomes a method of the internal `<Module>` class.  Only C++/CLI code can call that function.

Comment: the code above : return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(dataEnc)); and it works fine.

what i'm trying : return Aes256._GetString(dataEnc);
there is no error but it's just not get called, also the it won't even run all the code above that

Comment: @HansPassant Could be called in C# via reflection presumably? And once you use reflection you could create a delegate against it, obviating the need for reflection in later calls

Comment: If you are recompiling it anyway you could just rename the class to something C# will accept